# What is the equivalent in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following javascript code and what will it equivalent to jquery.

```
var sup= 'WebkitTransform' in document.body.style ||
         'MozTransform' in document.body.style ||
      'msTransform' in document.body.style ||
           'OTransform' in document.body.style ||
       'transform' in document.body.style;
```

Comment: Why would you need jQuery here???

Comment: @A.Wolff I was looking whether we can do in jquery

Comment: That's absolutely not the purpose of jQuery, your code would be better than any jQuery equivalent

Comment: @A.Wolff ur suggestions makes sense thanx

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy e.g.:

```
'WebkitTransform' in $(document.body).attr("style")
```

but there is no need in that: it is for sure worse for performance. Maybe not that big but worse.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
var $body = $("body");
    var sup = ($body.css("WebkitTransform") || $body.css("MozTransform") || $body.css("msTransform") || $body.css("OTransform") || $body.css("transform")) ? true : false
```

Though I wonder why would you need to use jQuery, since jQuery is JavaScript, you can use that one as well.